# Error while getting Identity matrix after performing matrix multiplication between a matrix and its inverse

Tags: math, error-handling, matrix-multiplication, matrix-inverse, cublas

Using CUBLAS I performed matrix inversion of a N x N matrix containing random floating point (single precision) values upto 6 place decimals. After obtaining the Inverse (and verified using [this website](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/)) , I multiplied the obtained Inverse matrix and the original matrix (using CUDA matrix multiplication program ) hoping to get exact Identity matrix. But the identity matrix had some error in it. Can you please explain me why this happened ? I am even attaching the output of my program below.

[image: 15x15 matirx]
[image: 3x3 matrix]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is numerical error. It is common due to finite precision of computations. You could start from here.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_error

Comment: No, and actually some times it is impossible to represent a number precisely with the type of float/double on computer. For example '0.1'

Comment: Is it fine if I submit the program along with attaching possible errors (such as this) to my guide? As the verification method(identity matrix) isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: Fine. The standard way of checking float number result  is 'approximately equal' with a predefined allowed error such as 1e-4.